# In which game modes/maps do I get airdropped IFV?

Tags: battlefield-3

I'm having hard time doing the *Fatal Drop* assignment, since I don't get to use airdropped IFV too often. Seems that it's only available on limited number of maps/game modes combinations. So which are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can get them in the End game maps playing conquest. Your team will have to hold the location that has the airdrops for you to spawn on them.

Comment: ok, that much I know, but is that the case of every EG map? Also, what about other modes: rush and CTF?

Comment: It is in the map Nebandan Flats but not sure about the other maps. There is only 4 maps so try them out.

Comment: The airdropped IFV appears in **all** end game maps, **only** in Conquest mode